# How do I define NSLayoutConstraint for a right alignment within a stack view?

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, nslayoutconstraint

I am try to align an icon, some text, and a result within two stack views.

The first stack view is vertical and contains X horizontal stack views. Each of the horizontal stack views contains a `UIImageView` and two `UILabel`s.

While the `UIImageView` and the first `UILabel` should be aligned to the left, the last `UILabel` should align on the right side of the stack view.

The whole UI is generated in code, in this case C# but I don't think it is hard to convert Swift code to C#. After reading a bit about iOS UI, I think I can solve this with `NSLayoutConstraint`, but I don't know how to use it — my current attempts always end in an exception.

This is how I am setting my constraint currently:

```
dataStack.Constraints.Append(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(percentageLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, dataStack, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 0));
```

**Edit:**
This is how it currently look like: https://puu.sh/Ddlrx/ab36d7c864.png but the percentage should be right aligned so each line ends at the same place.

And this is my current code which generates the UI: https://pastebin.com/pvMTGx0U

The constraints in the current code are a 1:1 copy of a working implementation in XCode Designer... I don't get it why it won't work this way in my widget. :/

Comment: Can you add a image of current output

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I edited my post above with a screenshot and the current code. I'm trying this now for 6 hours and still it won't work... so either I think the wrong way for iOS UI design or I just need a break <.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a vertical Stackview with

```
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.spacing = 2
```

Add top, leading, trailing, bottom constraints. Don't add height constraint. It will be calculated from subviews.

Next add n Horizontal stackviews as arranged subviews with

```
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
stavkView.spacing = 2
```

Now add an Image view and two labels in each horizontal stackview.

Don't add leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints to these image view and labels.

Add width and height constraint for each image view

Assign equal width to lbl1 and lbl2

```
lbl1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lbl2.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Change `lbl2`'s `textAlignemnt` to `.right`

```
lbl2.textAlignment = .right
```

Now you'll get this

[image]

**OR**

Instead of adding equal with to lbl1 and lbl2

set content hugging priority for lbl2

```
lbl2.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

Now lbl2's width will shrink to fit its text. lbl1 will take remaining width